# 3D sphere with texture in Canvas (HTML5)

Tags: html, canvas, 3d, geometry, textures

Can we bind texture with **Canvas (HTML5) 3D Sphere** ?

I am referring to this example - http://www.bitstorm.it/blog/en/2011/05/3d-sphere-html5-canvas/

Thanks,

**EDIT :**

alternate link -

http://sebleedelisle.com/2011/02/html5-canvas-3d-particles-uniform-distribution/

Comment: You might get a better response by saying "canvas" and not "HTML5".

Comment: Agreed, Question edited.

Comment: check this page http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas3dtexture_0.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible just like http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas3dtexture_0.2/ . But if you actually looking for 3d texture you must use [WEBGL texture](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=507)

A nice introduction can be found in [Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=507)